# Problems in pushing files to the gitlab repository

Tags: git

I am new to the git so please be patient with me :)

So I have created a repo in GitLab and I am trying to push the code into the repo.

Steps I used: 1. git clone [project URL]

2. git init
3. git remote add origin [project URL]
4. git add [folder name]
5. git commit -m [your message]
6. git push -u origin master

Now when i push the code i get this error

```
git push -u origin master
To [project URL]
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to [project URL]
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

My repo :

[image]

My directory i wanna push to the repo:

[image]

Comment: You need to pull the latest changes from your `master` branch .  try  first `git pull origin master`  and then commit and push.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the newly created repository.
2. Select the URL in the top-right section.
3. Go to the folder where you want to check out the project in the
   terminal. No need to create a new folder for the project.
4. Enter the Git clone command, and change the URL to the URL you just
   copied:

**$ git clone URL**

5. You can now go to the folder and check whether it is a Git folder by
   running the following command

:
**$ git status**

1. To commit the change, we run the following command:

**$ git commit -m "Added readme file"**

7. Now, we have the commit in our local Git repository, but to send it
   to the GitLab server, we have to enter another command:

**$ git push -u origin master**

Comment: Hi i did the same thing and i got the error that i mentioned in my question

Comment: bro after clone you again go in git and again add the url of repositery and then commit and push the code its will work fine